# CUDA compilation errors on Mac

Tags: c, cuda, makefile

I'm using the following Makefile to compile a CUDA C program. This follows pretty much the same pattern that I use in most of my C projects.

```
TARGET = bfs

GCC = nvcc
CUDA_INSTALL_PATH := /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5
LIBS := -I. -I$(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/include
CUDA_LIBS := -L$(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/lib -lcudart

SRCDIR = src
OBJDIR = obj
BINDIR = bin
INClDIR = includes

SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cu)
INCLUDES := $(wildcard $(INClDIR)/*.h)
OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.cu=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
rm = rm -f

$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    mkdir -p $(BINDIR)
    $(GCC) -o $@ $(LIBS) -c $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Linking complete!"

$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.cu
    @$(GCC) $(LIBS) -c *.cu -o $@
    @echo "Compiled "$<" successfully!"

.PHONEY: clean
clean:
    @$(rm)   $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Cleanup complete!"
remove: clean
    @$(rm) $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)
    @echo "Executable removed!"
```

I get the following error

```
mkdir -p bin
nvcc -o bin/bfs -I. -I/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/include -c obj/main.o obj/square.o
nvcc fatal   : A single input file is required for a non-link phase when an outputfile is specified
make: *** [bin/bfs] Error 1
```

What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: `-c` does not belong in the link step.  So change this: `$(GCC) -o $@ $(LIBS) -c $(OBJECTS)` to this: `$(GCC) -o $@ $(LIBS)  $(OBJECTS)`

Comment: Now I'm getting clang: error: no such file or directory: '*.cu'
clang: error: no input files
make: *** [obj/main.o] Error 1 However there are two files of *.cu type in the src directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemed to work for me:

```
TARGET = bfs

SRCDIR = src
OBJDIR = obj
BINDIR = bin
INClDIR = includes

CUDA_INSTALL_PATH := /usr/local/cuda
GCC := $(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/bin/nvcc
LIBS := -I. -I$(SRCDIR) -I$(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/include -I$(INClDIR)
CUDA_LIBS := -L$(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/lib64 -lcudart

SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cu)
INCLUDES := $(wildcard $(INClDIR)/*.h)
OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.cu=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
rm = rm -f

$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET) : $(OBJECTS)
        mkdir -p $(BINDIR)
        $(GCC) -o $@  $(OBJECTS)
        @echo "Linking complete!"

$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.cu
        @$(GCC) $(LIBS) -c $(SRCDIR)/*.cu -odir $(OBJDIR)
        @echo "Compiled "$<" successfully!"

.PHONEY: clean
clean:
        @$(rm)   $(OBJECTS)
        @echo "Cleanup complete!"
remove: clean
        @$(rm) $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)
        @echo "Executable removed!"
```

I tested on linux.  You will need to change `CUDA_INSTALL_PATH` back to wherever it is on your machine.

Note that your use of `*.cu` on the compile step results in a single invocation of `nvcc` to compile all the source files.  There's nothing wrong with this per se, but it will only generate a single "Compiled ... successfully!" message, as there is only one invocation of `nvcc` to create all the objects.

Comment: This is what I get when I try to use this make rc/main.cu:1:10: fatal error: '../include/headers.h' file not found
#include "../include/headers.h"

Comment: OK you didn't provide any code, so I don't know what your source code structure is.  You don't need to do this: `#include "../include/headers.h"`  Instead you can just do this:  `#include "headers.h"` in your source files.  If you wish to leave your source code as-is then you can modify the Makefile line from this: `LIBS := -I. -I$(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/include -I$(INClDIR)`  to this: `LIBS := -I. -I$(SRCDIR) -I$(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/include -I$(INClDIR)`

Comment: I went ahead and made this change to the Makefile I posted as there should be no harm in doing so.

Comment: I first tried  using "headers.h" which gave the same error. This gave the same error so I changed the LIBS as you suggested. Now I have this error.

Comment: /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/bin/nvcc -o bin/bfs obj/main.o obj/square.o
nvlink fatal   : Could not open input file 'obj/main.o'

Comment: Basically I have two .cu files inside my src and headers.h inside my includes. The Makefile is in the root.

Comment: Yes, I have the same structure, and it works for me on linux.  What files are in your `obj` directory?  Can you find `main.o` and `square.o` anywhere in your directory structure?  Are you using the Makefile exactly as I have shown it, except for the modification to the `CUDA_INSTALL_PATH` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96749/discussion-between-antithesis-and-robert-crovella).